# Does entropy flatten spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, thermodynamics, spacetime

Forgive me if this is a non-question, but I could not find anything regarding this.

I only know parts of GR, and I am not familiar with the math.

Since energy and matter density curve spacetime, does this mean that when entropy increases, spacetime curvature flattens?

Hypothetically, if the universe is destined to reach total entropy and be in equilibrium, would this mean that the spacetime curvature of the universe be mostly flat?

Comment: The answer is a resounding "Maybe!". Did you look into "entropic gravity"? It's one of those congenial ideas that are full of problems when looked at closely, at the same time it's very tempting to put the onus for everything we don't fully understand on thermodynamics... how wrong can it be?